# Javascript toggle to show/hide division

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to customize my website.

I am trying to make a division arrow (fontawesome icon) to show/hide a division.

Here is my divisions..

```
<div class="welcome-cont">
</div>
<div class="welcome-cont" style="display: none">
    <div class="row">
        <p>hellllo?</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have another division which is my arrow and it is fixed somewhere on the page..

```
<span class="arrow-up fa fa-angle-double-up fa-3x"></span>
```

Here is my javascript but unfortunately it is not toggling no matter how I try...

```
$(".arrow-up").click(function() {
    $("div.welcome-cont").toggleClass("bounce");
});
```

Comment: Post you CSS and you can use simply $(".welcome-cont")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All is fine !! Instead of `toggleClass` you should use `toggle`

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".arrow-up").click(function() {
    $("div.welcome-cont").toggle("bounce");
});
});
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e11oojyh/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to show/hide your div

```
$(".arrow-up").click(function() {
    $("div.welcome-cont").toggle();
});
```